# Method not returning a value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method that should return the domain name of the current user in a label.text. I call the method in the load event of the form but nothing comes up, no errors in the code either. Maybe im starting the object wrong? It works if i put the method code in the load event directly.

```
public partial class Main Form
{
  public Main()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public string getCurrentDomain()
  {
    return domainNameValue.Text = Environment.UserDomainName;
  }

  public void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.getCurrentDomain();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value if you set a break point and hover over the variable?

Comment: You have a method called "getSomething" and yet, what it does is it *set*s something. Try to change your method or rename it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `Main_Load` function you are creating a new form instead of changing the current form, The correct code is:

```
public void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                          
{
   this.getCurrentDomain();                                    
}
```

Or if you wnat to have another form just show it using `main.show()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are creating new instance of Main class in your `Main_Load` method. So, the method `getCurrentDomain()` change label text of the instance that you are creating not the label in the form where `Main_Load` is executed.

Also the body of method `getCurrentDomain()` violates the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) because that method is generating side effect which changes text of a label. But the name of method suggest only that the current domain name is being returned.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
public string getCurrentDomain()                                                                      // Method: Get current domain
    {
        domainNameValue.Text = Environment.UserDomainName;    
        return Environment.UserDomainName;  
    }
```

Comment: Can you suggest why it would matter? I just tested the set up in my code and I get the value returned despite the unconventional assign-and-return approach.

Comment: There is no problem in the `getCurrentDomain` function. Assigning (a=b) will results the assigned value.